# variable hides a variable in an enclosing block error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

The code

```
Using m_objSqlConnection = New SqlCeConnection(m_strConnectionString)

End Using
```

produces the following error:

> Variable 'm_objSqlConnection' hides a variable in an enclosing block

Comment: copy "m_objSqlConnection", Find (ctrl+shift+f), paste "m_objSqlConnection", press enter. You will find that m_objSqlConnection is already defined in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

The "m_" prefix suggests that you have a member variable with that name.  When you use a `Using` statement you are declaring a variable that exists only in the scope of that block.  If you already have a member variable with that name then why would you want a local variable with the same name?  You need to decide whether a local variable or a member variable is more appropriate and stick with the one option.  If you're disposing the connection at the end of the `Using` block then you're apparently not reusing it so I'd think that getting rid of the member variable is the way to go.